# How to keep Wireless turned on on my modem all the time

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have a `Dlink 2750u` Modem (V1 firmware 1.00) and I am looking for a solution for keeping my wireless turned on, basically my problem is my little brother who we keep the modem in his room turns off the Wifi when ever I go out so no one else can use the internet (He is connected through wire).

I am looking for a way to either disable the button on the modem to turn off the Wifi, or at least a method to keep it turned on ( like a script running on the modem itself).

I have a few ideas in my head to fix this problem but they are a little extreme:

The first one is write a little program that enter the modem admin page and check if Wifi is disabled, if yes turns it back ON and install it on his computer.

The second one is to completely remove the button or unsolder it, but I don't like this kind of irreversible solutions

I checked if my modem is supported by DD-WRT which might give me a little flexibility to run scripts but unfortunately my modem is not supported.

Comment: The solution to such problems is not always technical.

Comment: @tetech unfortunatly in this case, it is, you see my little brother is a teenager talking with him is not going to solve this problem, neither is the violence.